# PowerBuilder Customize Error Message on ItemChanged

Tags: sybase, powerbuilder, datawindow

On ItemChanged event of datawindow, I have to prompt a message on wrong input.
The issue is: When I use messagebox(), It prompt message correctly but field is not being blank and by pressing TAB, the control is being shifted to next field. (means its accepting the wrong value by pressing TAB key again)
Here is simple code for above scenario:

```
    if lb_error = true then
        messagebox('Info','Only Digits Are Allowed ~nAll Digits Cannot Be 0')
        this.object.payer_phone[1] =''
    end if
```

Then I tried **Modify** property, Its working fine but Is there any possibility to change Its title and icon??  I am using following code and , Kindly help me.

```
   if lb_error = true then
      this.Modify("payer_phone.ValidationMsg='Only Digits Are Allowed ~nAll Digits Cannot Be 0'")
      this.object.payer_phone[1] =''
      return 1
   end if
```

I am using PowerBuilder 12.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the PowerBuilder help:

> Return Values
>   Set the return code to affect the outcome of the event:
>
> 0 (Default) Accept the data value
>
> 1 Reject the data value and do not allow focus to change
>
> 2 Reject the data value but allow the focus to change

So in your case you need to RETURN 1 from the itemchanged event.

Since you are handling this error in itemchanged you need to 'bypass' the itemerror event.  You do this by placing a RETURN 1 there.

By triggering the error in the itemchanged event you can create a custom error messagebox or use the system default and control the title, icon, buttons, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming payer_phone is the field being edited, I believe you need SetText() instead of setting the underlying value in the data set.

To understand this difference, you need to know that for data entry, there is a control "floating above" the DataWindow, moving from field to field with focus. When the entered data is accepted, the value in the floating control is flushed to the data set of the DW. GetText() and SetText() deal with that floating control. Your code is changing the DW data set. After the first error, the next time you press Tab, no change in the control has been detected, so the functionality that fires when data changes doesn't occur, and your error code never kicks off.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the icon and title by using the same function MessageBox with a different signature :
MessageBox ( title, text {, icon {, button {, default } } } )

HTH,
Ali

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the icon and title by using the same function MessageBox with a different signature : MessageBox ( title, text , icon , button , default )

HTH, Ali